# Change database setup now having error even after reverting to orginal setup (Laravel 5)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I tried to experiment with my Laravel 5 database.php, originally

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'forge'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

then I changed to

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'mydb',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

now I am having this error even if I revert to the original setup?

### #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

env file contains

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Comment: Is your database user's password 'password'?

Comment: Did the first original credentials work?

Comment: If it did work, can you post your .env file?

Comment: Please check your database.php: Does it has  'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql') OR  'default' => 'mysql'. Take a look on your .env on line DB_CONNECTION=mysql

Comment: No, your password is 'secret'

Comment: Try with this password

Comment: Wait, can you go to phpmyadmin and see if you have the database 'mydb'?

Comment: secret or password do not work.

Comment: defaul db is default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'), I can not go to phpmyadmin that's my problem having the error I posted.

Comment: Okay I understand, did you create a database called 'mydb' ?

Comment: Try with no password. Usually when you install the local server, it will be no password or 'root' itself

Answer (score 1):

In the first part of your `config/database.php` there's should be something like:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

make sure you didn't change that.

Anyway, as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#environment-configuration) you should use a local `.env` file for your database configuration.